# How to sort a listview in alphabetical order

Tags: java, android, sorting, android-listview, android-adapter

I've been following this tutorial [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358) on how to make my own Android launcher. I can currently display all the installed apps on my phone in a listview. How can I edit this code so that the list is in alphabetical order?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_apps_list);

        loadApps();
        loadListView();
        addClickListener();
    }

private PackageManager manager;
private List<AppDetail> apps; 
private void loadApps(){
    manager = getPackageManager();
    apps = new ArrayList<AppDetail>();

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
    for(ResolveInfo ri:availableActivities){
        AppDetail app = new AppDetail();
        app.label = ri.loadLabel(manager);
        app.name = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        app.icon = ri.activityInfo.loadIcon(manager);
        apps.add(app);
    }
}

private ListView list;    
private void loadListView(){
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.apps_list);

    ArrayAdapter<AppDetail> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AppDetail>(this, 
            R.layout.list_item, 
            apps) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(convertView == null){
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            ImageView appIcon = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_icon);
            appIcon.setImageDrawable(apps.get(position).icon);

            TextView appLabel = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_label);
            appLabel.setText(apps.get(position).label);

            TextView appName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name);
            appName.setText(apps.get(position).name);

            return convertView;
        }
    };

    list.setAdapter(adapter);           
}

private void addClickListener(){        
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos,
                long id) {
            Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(apps.get(pos).name.toString());
            AppsListActivity.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the first answer is the correct and most obvious way to do it, I believe an answer requires a full example:

```
Collections.sort(apps, new Comparator<AppDetail>() {

    /* This comparator will sort AppDetail objects alphabetically. */

    @Override
    public int compare(AppDetail a1, AppDetail a2) {

        // String implements Comparable
        return (a1.label.toString()).compareTo(a2.label.toString());
    }
});
```

This will sort the `AppDetail` objects alphabetically by their `label` field.

Do this before calling `setAdapter()`.

Comment: I get an error over compareTo saying cannot resolve method 'compareTo(Java.Lang.CharSequence)'

Comment: I have assumed that `AppDetail.name` is a `String`

Comment: Okay thanks it works. But i've messed up, could you help me out again? instead of a1.name and a2.name I need it to be a1.label and a2.label. However AppDetail.label is a CharSequence. Can I sort it like that or would I have to convert it to a string first ?

Comment: it works! thanks so much for the help. I hope you find your way out of the matrix :)

Answer (score 4):

Sort your `apps` `List` before putting it in the `ArrayAdapter`, [using `Collections.sort()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%3CT%3E,%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E%29).

Comment: what about ArrayAdapter.sort()?

Comment: @Blackbelt could you post an example?

Comment: @Blackbelt: You know, I have never noticed that method. It uses `Collections.sort()` under the covers, though looking at the source I think the behavior varies a bit depending upon whether or not a filter is applied. It certainly would seem like an option, if you needed to sort on the fly. For a list that starts off in the sorted order, I'd still `sort()` it before putting it in the `ArrayAdapter`. My apologies for not having noticed that option!

Comment: no reason to apologize. And I agree with you about  sorting the dataset before submitting it to the adapter

Answer (score 2):

```
Collections.sort(contactList,
                            new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {

                                @Override
                                public int compare(Map<String, String> o1,
                                        Map<String, String> o2) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    String name1 = o1.get("name");
                                    String name2 = o2.get("name");
                                    if (name1 == null)
                                        return -1;
                                    return name1.compareTo(name2);
                                }

                            });

                }
```